# One IBAction for multiple custom prototype cells with buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

Using storyboard, I have a table view controller containing multiple dynamic prototype cells.  One of the cells is a custom dynamic prototype cell (for which I created a subclass) containing a label and a switch.  I have the action for the switch wired to an action method (say switchChanged:) in the view controller.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I configure and return the cell appropriate for the specified index.  So far so good.

The problem:  my application has multiple instances of these custom cells, so how do I differentiate which switch has changed?  One thought is that in the view controller I can create a member switch for each cell and link them to a specific cell switch when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for the first time.  Then I can use these member switches to compare with the switch that is passed into switchChanged:.

I know that I can try it and get an immediate answer, but I was hoping for a discussion of how other developers do what I am trying to do.  Is this the best/worst/ok approach and what are practical alternatives?

Regards,

--John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this situation once (not with switches, but I believe it applies just the same). I've managed to get around it by subclassing the object class and adding the required properties/methods inside the subclass.

When calling the action, your sender will be the subclass, and you can access your added code there.

I don't know if it is the case, but if you're only trying to change a value, you should use bind the switch value to the property when creating the object. It will not even need an IBAction to call.

EDIT: Example:

```
@interface MySwitch : UISwitch
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger someProperty;
@end
```

Then, every time you create a cell, you can set "someProperty" to anything you want.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // yada yada yada...
  UITableViewCell *cell;
  // yada yada yada...

  [cell.myLinkedSwitch  setSomeProperty:indexPath.row];
  return(cell);
}
```

Unless you're not creating your cells using the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Then you probably should use bindings to get your value to the right place.

Comment: I follow what what you are saying, it seems to apply to only one instance of the custom cell.  But how can I differentiate between the switches of multiple cell instances?

Comment: So let's see if I understand.  I can add a property, say instanceID, to the subclass.  I can then set this property for each cell the first through cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Then when switchChanged: is called, I can use instanceID to determine which switch has changed state.  Seem correct?

Comment: Almost! You'll set the property for each cell every time a cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. If you have 30 cells, that function will be called 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a separate subclass, I just stored the row in each button Disabled Title property.  This worked very will with little effort.  This first code is in the CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *strRow = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",useRow];
[btnPreferredChk setTitle:strRow forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Then my action method for the button uses that value to perform the appropriate activity.

```
- (IBAction)goStorePick:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *useButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  useButton = sender;
  NSInteger *storeRow = [[useButton titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled] integerValue];

  NSString *CMIMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"goStorePick Method Executed at Row: %i", storeRow];

  [self shwMessage:CMIMsg];
}
```

This worked well for me.